# Treat image and link as one element

Tags: html, responsive

I'm making a responsive website. At the bottom I have a phone icon, a phone number, a mail icon and a mail address – all in one line.

```html
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/13/10/30/icon-157358_960_720.png" height="150px" width="111px">
<a href="tel:123456">123456</a>
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/13/17/30/mail-1454734_960_720.png" height="150px" width="150px">
<a href="mailto:asdf@gmail.com">asdf@gmail.com</a>
```

In full window, it looks like this:
[phone img][phone number] [mail img][mail address]

When I resize the window they end up like this:
[phone img][phone number][mail img] 
[mail address]

I want the icons and texts to stick together, like this:
[phone img][phone number]
[mail img][mail address]

I tried encasing them with div and span, but none worked. I also googled "html two elements stick together" without result. 
It feels really basic and I feel quite stupid, but I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<a href="tel:123456">
    <img src="phone.jpg">123456
</a>

<a href="mailto:asdf@gmail.com">
    <img src="mail.jpg">asdf@gmail.com</a>
```

use css to add paddings and responsive behaviours

Comment: I tried that but still the same result. The mail address jumps and the mail image stays.

Comment: How does your css look like?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is make both elements part of an unordered list and display that as two separate blocks on mobile. When the viewport grows (`@media screen and (min-width: 600px)`), the list elements (`<li>`) will display next to each other, thanks to `display: inline-block;`.

```css
  ul {
  list-style: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="phone.jpg">
    <a href="tel:123456">123456</a></li>
  <li><img src="mail.jpg">
    <a href="mailto:asdf@gmail.com">asdf@gmail.com</a></li>
</ul>
```